# HD Detected as null When Installing El Capitan

Tags: installation, osx-elcapitan

I created a bootable image on a USB drive using this method:

https://www.macissues.com/2015/10/01/how-to-overcome-os-x-10-11-el-capitan-not-installing/

Basically, formatting a USB drive, calling it INSTALLER, and using a previously downloaded installer to create the bootable image on the thumb drive with this command:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/INSTALLER --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app --nointeraction
```

This seems to work, and the install process does indeed kick off after reboot, but now the problem is that when I get to the screen where I am asked to select which drive to install OS X on, I am given two choices:  The INSTALLER drive (a USB drive I am booting from) and "(null)".  The icon above (null) is that of a standard hard drive, so I select it and am given the error message that there is not enough space on (null) to install OSX.

So, first, that is not the name of the drive. And second, according to my disk utility I have over 140 gigs free on the drive so I know this is just a false error on the part of the installer.

So how to resolve? I have tried installing several times and I get the same result each time so I know it is not a one-off problem.  Why is the hard drive detecting as (null)?

The 251 gig volume is a single volume with Mac OS Extended (Journaled) format, and currently is running Yosemite:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symantec products are poison to Macs, it seems.  What was happening in my case is that there was a product called Symantec Endpoint Encryption that had encrypted the entire drive, which was hiding it from the installer.  Once I figured out how to decrypt the drive using the Symantec utility I was able to run the install without problems.

I hope this helps someone else.  Good luck!